# Shortcut key combination to add pragma marks in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

Before Xcode 11, I could simply use `cmd + option + /` to add pragma marks (`// MARK: -`) above the extensions of my project's classes. However, in Xcode 11, I am unable to find such shortcut key combination to add such marks.
Could anyone please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 9):

One way, to make your life easier till someone finds if the shortcut can be re-included in later Xcode versions could be a **Code Snippet**:

- write this anywhere in a swift file for example: `// MARK: - <#Description#>`
- select it
- double tap/right click > Create Code Snippet
- give it your `Completion Shortcut` (like `m` or `mark`)
- now go back to your file and try to type `m` or `mark` and hit enter to make the code snippet appear for you

Comment: Yes, I have done the same in my Xcode right now. However, I wonder why they removed it.